# Esper Database Adapter insert Data to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, configuration, insert, esper

I am new to esper. I want to store in mysql database event when esper identify event which satisfy the eql query.First i look up this example [Esper: How to configure Esper to connect a Relational Database, through a JDBC, using Esper's configuration API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735044/esper-how-to-configure-esper-to-connect-a-relational-database-through-a-jdbc) and try to come up with solution.

```
<plugin-loader name="EsperIODBAdapter"  class-name="com.espertech.esperio.db.EsperIODBAdapterPlugin">
    <config-xml>

    <esperio-db-configuration>
        <jdbc-connection name="database">
            <drivermanager-connection class-name="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CEP_DEMO"
                                      user="user" password="password"/>
            <connection-settings auto-commit="true" catalog="TEST"/>
        </jdbc-connection>
        <dml connection="database" stream="event" >
        <sql>INSERT INTO BasicEvent(userId,eventId,eventUsage,eventDateTime) values(?,?,?,?) </sql>
        <bindings>
            <bindings>
                <parameter pos="1" property="userId"/>
                <parameter pos="2" property="eventId"/>
                <parameter pos="3" property="eventUsage"/>
                <parameter pos="4" property="eventDateTime"/>
            </bindings>
        </bindings>
    </dml>
    </esperio-db-configuration>

    </config-xml>
    </plugin-loader>
```

Then when i run the application it didn't insert data to table.I want to know my method is correct or is there any other method to configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check that no exceptions are logged or thrown and the you are indeed inserting into a stream called "event" with "insert into event ..."